# Taking screenshots of urls in file takes only single screenshot using python

Tags: python

I have debugged this , it loops through all links of file but saves only single screenshot

---

```
    import sys
    
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QTimer
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView, QWebEngineSettings
    
    
    class Screenshot(QWebEngineView):
    
        def capture(self, url, output_file):
            self.output_file = output_file
            self.load(QUrl(url))
            self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loaded)
            # Create hidden view without scrollbars
            self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontShowOnScreen)
            self.page().settings().setAttribute(
                QWebEngineSettings.ShowScrollBars, False)
            self.show()
    
        def on_loaded(self):
            size = self.page().contentsSize().toSize()
            self.resize(size)
            # Wait for resize
            QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.take_screenshot)
    
        def take_screenshot(self):
            self.grab().save(self.output_file, b'PNG')
            self.app.quit()
    
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    s = Screenshot()
    s.app = app
    file1 = open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\allsub1 - Copy.txt", "r")
    Lines = file1.readlines()
    counter = 1
    for line in Lines:
        s.capture(line, 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\screenshots\\' + str(counter) + '.png')
        counter += 1
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

here in last line i am facing trouble , it saves only single screenshot

Comment: add `counter += 1` inside the for loop

Comment: Hi @Tuqay added still same issue , saving single screenshot with last counter value

Comment: You do know what they mean when they say increment *within* the loop, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

It’s saving all of the screenshots but with the same name. So when it’s done, only the last PNG file is left. You just need to increment `counter` in the loop.

Comment: Hi @Howlium , added still same issue , saving single screenshot with last counter value

Comment: @smith I would expect this answer to work, are you able to edit you post with this included to show where you have put it?

Comment: Please also be sure to put those last couple of lines in the formatted code section; my suspicion is that the indentation may just incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Howlium , formatted my code and its as per indentation

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue . Replaced sys.exit(app.exec_()) with just app.exec_() and it works fine.
thank yu all.

Comment: Awesome, I’m glad you worked that out. Debugging is always tricky when there are multiple issues at the same time!